# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range, changing array of double to array of string

Tags: arrays, swift, string, multidimensional-array, double

I want to change my array of double to array of string with this code:

```
var arrayOfDouble: [[Double]] = [[..]]

func change(_ doubles: [[Double]]) -> [[String]]{
    var result:[[String]] = [[]]
    
    for i in 0..<doubles.count{
        for j in 0..<doubles[i].count{
            result[i][j] = String(doubles[i][j])
        }
    }

    return result
}

var lll:[[String]] = change(arrayOfDouble)

print(lll)
```

But the app crashed with a warning:
`Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

I tried to test the function in playground and it resulting an error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18bd55e10).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: The assignment to `result[i][j]` crashes because `result` is an *empty* array.

Comment: A simpler solution would be `result = doubles.map { row in row.map { String($0) }}`